# How to create a moving HUD?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I didn't know how to title this, but there is an effect video games generally have that I would like to achieve. If you have, for example, a turret in your vision, a healthbar will appear on it. if you are far away from the turret, the health bar *will not* be smaller. Also, the healthbar is *right above the turret*. How can I achieve this effect? Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with Blender's game engine. Generally speaking, you can draw your 'HUD' in view(or camera) space. That is, you project the position of turret to 2D and draw HUD with a size in view space. Also you need to be aware of depth test, draw order and blend functions.

Comment: If you're using an overlay scene for your HUD, try using an orthographic camera, that should keep it the health bars the same size no matter what the distance.

Comment: @christai I understand that, but I need the bar to always be above the turret. If I just put it in an overlay, it will always be where I put it.